# reporte tabla combinada mysql php

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando una tabla con registros que tengo en una base de datos.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es como lo necesito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como lo estoy realizando:

```html
$sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT `trabajadorID`, nombre, `puesto`, min(`fechaInicial`) fechaIn, max(`fechaFinal`) fechaFin FROM `contratacion` GROUP by puesto,`trabajadorID` ORDER BY `trabajadorID`, fechaInicial DESC");


foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $value) {
    # code...

echo '
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$value['trabajadorID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$value['nombre'].'</td>
            <td>'.$value['puesto'].'</td>
            <td>'.$value['fechaIn'].'</td>
            <td>'.$value['fechaFin'].'</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

}
```

Alguna idea de como pueda lograr esto que necesito, ojala me puedan apoyar ya que no he podido.
Gracias por el apoyo.

Saludos.

Anexo mi tabla de base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el nuevo query utilizado:

SELECT trabajadorID, nombre,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT puesto) p, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT((fechaInicial))) f1,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT((fechaFinal) )) f2
FROM contratacion
GROUP by trabajadorID
ORDER by trabajadorID, f1 asc

el resultado hasta ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desde la consulta SQL creo que se podría con un `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: podrías mostrar la tabla de donde sacas los datos

Comment: Ya hice una consulta con GROUP_CONCAT como me lo indicaste, lo agregue hasta abajo del post

Comment: @PedroIslasReséndiz pero con group concat solo se deberían agrupar los puestos, ¿por qué lo usaste para las fechas?

Comment: para que cada puesto tenga su fecha inicial y final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes construir tu consulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT `trabajadorID`, 
       nombre, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`puesto` SEPARATOR '\n') Listado,
       GROUP_CONCAT(fechaInicial, ' / ',FechaFinal SEPARATOR '\n') FechasInicioYTermino,
       min(`fechaInicial`) fechaIn, 
       max(`fechaFinal`) fechaFin 
FROM `contratacion` 
GROUP by `trabajadorID`, nombre
ORDER BY `trabajadorID`, fechaInicial DESC
```

Donde:

- Agrupamos de manera concatenada todos los puestos que ocupa una persona (*asi aunque los valores sean distintos, como pertenecen o estan asociados a un empleado en común podemos reducirlos y dejarlos en una sola celda*)
- Para el caso de las fechas podemos aplicar la misma idea de agruparlas de manera concatenada solamente separándolas por algún símbolo
- Podemos enviar con un salto de línea cada puesto de trabajo con ayuda de un [separator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Te recomiendo el uso de GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(...) para evitar problemas con los valores nulos

Comment: Requiero que cada puesto tenga su fecha inicial y fecha final

Comment: @PedroIslasReséndiz revisa mi edición